# I need help proving the addition of intervals

Tags: real-analysis

Prove: $[a,b]+[c,d] = [a+c,b+c] \cup [b+c,b+d] = [a+c, b+d]$

I tried using the foil method but I ended up with the term $a+d$ which doesn't appear anywhere.

Comment: Do it by elements.  if $w \in [a,b] + [c,d]$ then $w = e+f$ for some $e \in [a,b]$ and $f$ in $[c,d]$ so $a+b \le e+f=2 \le c+d$ so $w \in [a+c,b+d]$.

Comment: @fleablood how did you get  $2 \leq c+d$ ? Thanks

Comment: The 2 is typo.  It was meant to be "w"  Actually, I didn't know I had submitted a comment.  I started to, and what I wrote above *does* show [a,b] + [c,d] $\subset $ [a+c,b+d].  But I realized proving the converse was a little harder.  So I wasn't going to submit the comment.  But I must have pressed the wrong key when I decided to look at something else.   Sorry.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks! This will definitely get me started.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of two closed intervals is a closed interval. That's pretty much stated in the question, but for completeness:

$$
[a+c,a+d] \subseteq [a,c]+[b,d]
$$
$$
[b+c,b+d] \subseteq [a,c]+[b,d]
$$
$$
[a+c,b+c] \subseteq [a,c]+[b,d]
$$
$$
[a+d,b+d] \subseteq [a,c]+[b,d]
$$
Also
$$
[a+c,a+d] \cup [a+d,b+d] = [a+c,b+d]
$$
$$
[a+c,b+c] \cup [b+c,b+d] = [a+c,b+d]
$$
So everything is contained in the interval $[a+c, b+d]$ and its bounds are met.